# UIImagePickerController allowsEditing=YES just for video

Tags: ios, video, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the `UIImagePickerController` to let the user select a photo or video. The problem I am facing, is I use my own image editor for photo's so want `allowsEditing=NO` for photo's, but video must be a certain length so I want `allowsEditing=YES` for video.

Setting `videoMaximumDuration` for the image picker works fine when recording video, but if selecting from the camera roll it only informs the user that the video is too long if `allowsEditing` is enabled.

So far, I can successfully change the `allowsEditing` property when using the camera by listening for the `ImageControlModeChanged` notification. Then I can change the property using:

```
- (void)imageCaptured:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo) {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    } else {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work when selecting from the Camera roll. I have monitored the notifications and can't see one that would be useful to change the `allowsEditing` property depending on which item was selected.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not creating 2 or even 4 `UIImagePickerController`s instead of messing around with notifications?

```
- (void) useCamera
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                  nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void) useCameraRoll
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)videoRoll
{

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                  nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)vidCam
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                  nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

After better understanding of the question I don't think it's possible. There are a few notification you can use but those are not documented anywhere or working on iOS7. If that is really the case the best solution I can think of is to use a 3rd party such as github.com/andrei200287/SAVideoRangeSlider and `allowsEditing = NO` for everything.

Comment: Thanks Sha, this doesn't solve the problem though. When using the pictureRoll I need editing=YES for video and editing=NO for photos

Comment: Hmm, see my edited answer. Change your allowsEditing to your needs. This cover all the states you can get from the cam\video selection.

Comment: I can confirm that the above code works for me. With video from the camera roll you will be able to edit it. For pics your won't be able to edit and the picker viewcontroller will dismiss itself upon selection of an image.

Comment: Yes that has 4 pickers for the 4 different scenarios, however how to switch between them? I don't want them to have to select what type of media they want before hand. They launch the camera roll, it displays both vids and photo's. How to limit the photo to not be editable but video to be?

Comment: In that case the only solution I can think of is to use a 3rd party such as https://github.com/andrei200287/SAVideoRangeSlider and allowsEditing = NO for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Simply allow editing on both image and video pick, but in didFinishPicking delegate method, for photo, choose original photo and not edited photo. However picker will still show that square box over image.

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
assign properties in view did load , not in imageCaptured method. it works fine

```
 videoController.delegate = self;
    videoController.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    videoController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:videoController.sourceType];
    videoController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Comment: How does this help? This just assigns `allowsEditing=YES` to anything that is selected or recorded which is not what I want.

Comment: @Aklesh You mind explaining your solution? I don't understand how it got to do with anything.

Comment: @AkleshRathaur Merge all your answers to one. This is not useful.